# How does type hinting work for the python dataclass in vscode?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I'm working on a class wrapper that behaves similar to the dataclasses.dataclass decorator.

To make a minimal example, I declare my custom `@pyclass` decorator like this, without any special type hints.

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
def pyclass(cls=None):
    return dataclass(cls)
```

I now create two identical classes, where on is wrapped in a `dataclasses.dataclass` and another is wrapped in the custom `pyclass`.

```
@pyclass
class TestPyClass:
    name: str 


@dataclass
class TestDataClass:
    name: str
```

This works in practice, the only issue is that vscode refuses to hint what arguments can be passed into the `__init__()` method.
While it displays the `__init__()` args of the `@dataclass` wrapped class correctly as `(name: str)`, similar behavior is not seen with the `@pyclass` decorator, where it displays only `(*args, **kwargs)`.

My suspicion is, that this is an issue with vscode type inference, if that is the case I will create a ticket with vscode, but I'd rather have a quick hack to get type inference for `__init__()`.

I was scouring the source code of `dataclass.py`, I think I found where the type hints are inferred from, but because I am calling the `dataclass()` method in `pyclass()`, the same code is run so I don't see the reason why the types are not inferred by vscode.

Edit: This was solved in Python 3.11
https://docs.python.org/3.11/whatsnew/3.11.html#pep-681-data-class-transforms

Comment: The edit should be posted as an answer (along with some additional information quoted from the PEP explaining why `pyclass` is treated differently than `dataclass` and how PEP 681 solves the problem).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was solved in Python 3.11

https://docs.python.org/3.11/whatsnew/3.11.html#pep-681-data-class-transforms